# Cocoa: Unable to access local DB of HTML5 web app when executed in webkit

Tags: iphone, cocoa, html, webkit, local-storage

Please help me in this what I am trying to do is I have

1. a Cocoa application with webkit in it.
2. an HTML5 based web application with local database.

I am trying to run this HTML5 application in cocoa application and get this error **"Error: Unknown error Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18."** same application is working fine in

1. Safari
2. iphone safari
3. UIWebkit

I have tried following things

```
@interface WebPreferences (WebPreferencesPrivate)
- (void) _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:(NSString *)path;
- (void) setDatabasesEnabled: (BOOL) databaseEnabled;
- (void) setLocalStorageEnabled: (BOOL) localStorageEnabled;
@end

WebPreferences* prefs = [self.mainWebVEW preferences];
[prefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:appdir];
[prefs setDatabasesEnabled:YES];
[prefs setLocalStorageEnabled:YES];
[prefs setDefaultFontSize:20];
```

only preference that seem working is font size.

Can anybody help me how to get over this?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Ankit

Answer (score 0):

ok so finally resolved it all you have to do is use one more private API

```
@interface WebView(WebViewPrivate)
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(id) origin database:(NSString *)databaseIdentifier;
@end

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(id) origin database:(NSString *)databaseIdentifier
{
static const unsigned long long defaultQuota = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
if ([origin respondsToSelector: @selector(setQuota:)]) {
    [origin performSelector:@selector(setQuota:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong: defaultQuota]];
} else { 
    NSLog(@"could not increase quota for %@", defaultQuota); 
}
}
```